# Every database have one different system user?

Tags: oracle

After I create a new database with DBCA, I will set a new password. Is the password for default user SYSTEM?

Then I can connect to this database with system and new_password. Does Oracle create different user named 'SYSTEM' for every database?

But if I want to connect SYS USER, I will need to use the adminstrator password (I entered when install oracle).

Does all database service use one common user SYS, but every database service have their own SYSTEM user, right?

I read some book, but these concept still confuse me, sorry for lots of questions.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/405/what-is-the-difference-between-sys-and-system-accounts-in-oracle-databases

Comment: I know the different about permission, but If you create multiple database, there will be multiple system user, or we can say every database has their own system user with different password.

Comment: Every database has it's own seperate set of users. So if you have 3 databases you will have three system and three sys users, each with their own passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After I create a new database with DBCA, I will set a new password. Is the password for default user SYSTEM?

Yes.

> Then I can connect to this database with system and new_password. Does Oracle create different user named 'SYSTEM' for every database?

Generally in Oracle we do have one instance and one database. There is only one `SYSTEM` user in Oracle Database.

For details:[AskTom: SYS, SYSDBA, SYSOPER, SYSTEM](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:2659418700346202574)

Comment: Thank you for this words: Generally in Oracle we do have one instance and one database